# When an ideal is locally comaximal with idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, idempotents

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and let for an ideal
$A$ of $R$, $\mathrm{Id}(A)$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by all idempotent
elements of $A$. Now let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that for
each prime ideal (or primary ideal) $P$ of $R$ we have $I\subseteq
\mathrm{Id}(P)$ or there exists $a^2=a\in P$ with $a-1\in I$. Show that
$I=0$.

Comment: Have you tried to use the fact that the set of zero divisors is a union of prime ideals

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270108/when-an-ideal-is-locally-comaximal-with-idempotentsrestated